# Mostly harmless, but ultimately pointless editing and re-editing of questions

Tags: discussion, edits

Once upon a time I asked a question about null pointer exceptions. I was programming in Java, but the context of my question was more broad. Occasionally I have come back to look at the question, as it is my main source of reputation. As of this year I noticed that the edits were getting silly. (I've since made them sillier, and I feel bad about that, but the goal was to illustrate a point).

[History of edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/218384/revisions)

- Edit 3 is pretty clever, it gets to the root of the question.
- Edit 4 is fine too: now that the title has changed, why not bring the question in line?
- Edit 5 is a getting silly: it mainly brings the question in line with someone's particular biases regarding the English language. It doesn't make the question clearer, except to person who made the edit.

It isn't a big problem! I'm just curious about the motivation. These are users with 100K reputation, so there must be a reason. The question was clear to begin with, and Edit 3 made it perfect. Will people just keep tweaking the phrasing to fit their particular biases forever?

Comment: One user with 100k who edited it is a moderator making your question more on-topic. Otherwise, your edit about cognition seems the most ridiculous one. The others are tweaking, yes; but, they're all reasonable.

Comment: Yes I agree, and I apologize: that's just my way of communicating. I should have just asked a question here right away instead of trying to "make a point".

Comment: also: reasonable is an interesting thing to call those. I could have made my pointless edit more reasonable and less over the top, but it wouldn't have made the question any clearer (just longer).

Comment: So if your question is _solely_ "will people continue editing?" The answer is almost certainly yes. It's a popular question, which means more people see it and more want to improve it. Eventually someone, maybe you, will get bored and roll it back to the original so the process can start again.

Comment: "Un re-corrected correction of corrected title edit to bring title correctness in line with my biases."...there's a mouthful

Comment: My take on all the revisions - Rev 2: not hugely important, but useful removal of fluff. Rev 3: smart improvement of title. Revs 4 and 5: seem pointless but benign. Perhaps 5 makes sense for SEO (i.e. for having NullPointerException Google searches find this)? Rev 6: ridiculous - the 'in the context of computer programming' seems out of place given that you are specifically asking about Java. Revs 7 through 9 - pointless but benign. So I agree that there's been a lot of bizarre and pointless editing here, but I share @Ben's opinion that you were the author of the worst edit so far.

Comment: Do note that you are monkeying with a *canonical question.*  Although you were the one who originally asked it, we now use this question as a common target for closing duplicate questions.  So it would be nice if it maintained a reasonably pristine form.  See [my edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/218384/revisions).

Comment: Yeah. My apologies again. I guess my real question was "when is it too much" and of course the answer is "when someone flags the question for moderation, and a mod decides it is too much". Sorry for wasting your time!

Comment: Out of curiosity, why did you change the title from `NullPointerException` to  `java.lang.NullPointerException`? Titles are supposed to be terse and concise. The `java.lang` adds no value and increases verbosity, especially if the question is tagged properly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you feel that a user is making a lot of edits that are only changing the style/formatting/word choice to be in line with their personal preferences without actually improving the content then you can flag the post for moderator attention and explain what you feel is wrong.  You should only do this if you notice the behavior regularly, rather than because of a single incidence.

If a particular post is attracting a lot of harmful or pointless edits, and it is not also attracting valuable edits, then you can consider flagging the post for moderator attention and asking for the post to be locked, preventing editing.  This should only be done for posts being edited to the point that it is becoming disruptive.